# How to correct a wrong projection of shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile with UTM zone 16. This projection is wrong. It must be UTM zone 32. How can I correct the projection?

When I convert (f-tool) to UTM zone 32, all the vector are rotated. The property of the layer shows funny numbers that is not correct:

```
xMin,yMin -4417494.80;6867783.98 : xMax,yMax -4416554.49;6869279.82
```

Correct property should be:

```
xMin,yMin 3410596.14;5317812.48 : xMax,yMax 3411876.35;5318694.50
```

Answer (score 4):

If your file is actually in UTM32 and not UTM16 then you need to update the .prj file not actually reproject the data which is what f-tools (ogr2ogr?) is actually doing. So go to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32632/ and download the [.prj file](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32632/prj/) provided there, save it with the same name as your shapefile and all should be fine.

**Note: You will need to make sure you have picked the right UTM projection (I just guessed with the link above.**

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert / reproject the shapefile!

Right-click on the layer in QGIS and "Set Layer CRS" - you will see the (incorrect) UTM Zone 16 indicated there, and you need only select the correct CRS (32).

HOWEVER ... to be really careful, I would strongly advise you to:

1. Delete the .prj file associated with the shapefile;
2. Add the shapefile to your canvas with other Zone 32 data (and only that data) to *ensure that it lines up properly*;
3. Set the layer CRS once you're sure it's correct.

You can 'save as' the layer to generate a shapefile with the correct .prj file at that point.